# Laravel not using faker locale in seeds

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I've set my `app.faker_locale` value to `en_CA`, but it is still using `en_US` for things like addresses, cities, etc.

How do I force faker to use Canadian locations in seeders?

Comment: did you run `php artisan config:clear` after setting it ?

Comment: @Ersoy yes I have. Did not help.